# Converting a java app engine call to GQL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to understand the source code on this file:
https://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/source/browse/trunk/geocell/src/test/java/com/beoui/utils/HowToUseGeocell.java

```
    // Use this in a query
    // In Google App Engine, you'll have something like below. In hibernate       (or whatever else), it might be a little bit different.
  //              String queryString = "select from ObjectToSave where      geocellsParameter.contains(geocells)";
//              Query query = pm.newQuery(queryString);
//          query.declareParameters("String geocellsParameter");
//          List<ObjectToSave> objects = (List<ObjectToSave>)query.execute(cells);
```

and port it to a GQL statement so I can use it in another language (node.js)
Does anyone understand what the GQL query would be? My understanding is that it's generating a query that filters on lat/long values but I don't understand what the format of that query would look like in plain GQL.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

From this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries

the .contains converts the list into multiple equality queries.